# Sequelize findAll function doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, consign

I'm making a project with Sequelize and I'm stuck on this step. The problem is that when i load http://localhost:3000/hygro and try to run hygro.js i get this error in return

TypeError: hygroData.findALL is not a function
at C:\Users\eddyg\hygrometer\routes\hygro.js:5:19
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\eddyg\hygrometer\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\eddyg\hygrometer\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\eddyg\hygrometer\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\eddyg\hygrometer\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\eddyg\hygrometer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\eddyg\hygrometer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (C:\Users\eddyg\hygrometer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
at expressInit (C:\Users\eddyg\hygrometer\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\eddyg\hygrometer\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

im really lost on what to do, im newer to javascript. Im working on this for my classes and its just been very furstrating for me

heres my structure:
(i didnt include my libs folder it included setup things, im not sure if its necessary, if needed i can show it.)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hygrometer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This will be the api for my hyrgometer data",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "node test.js"
  },
  "author": "Eddy Gallegos",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "consign": "^0.1.6",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.1",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.7"
  }
}
```

db.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

let db = null;

module.exports = app => {
    if (!db){
        const config = app.libs.config;
        const sequelize = new Sequelize(
            config.database,
            config.username,
            config.password,
            config.params
        );
        db = {
            sequelize,
            Sequelize,
            models: {}
        };
        const dir = path.join(__dirname,"models");
        fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
            const modelDir = path.join(dir, file);
            const model = require(modelDir)(sequelize,Sequelize.DataTypes);
            db.models[model.name]= model;
        });
        Object.keys(db.models).forEach(key => {
            db.models[key].options.classMethods.associate(db.models);
        });
    }
    return db;
};
```

app.js

```
const express =  require("express");
const consign = require ("consign");

const app = express();


consign()
    .include("libs/config.js")
    .then("db.js")
    .then("libs/middlewares.js")
    .then("routes")
    .then("libs/boot.js")
    .into(app);
```

routes/hygro.js

```
module.exports = app => {
    const hygroData = app.db.models.Readings;
    app.get("/hygro", (req,res) => {
        hygroData.findALL({}).then(data => {
            res.json({data:data});
    })
    });
}
```

models/locations.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataType) => {
    const Locations = sequelize.define("Locations", {
        id: {
            type: DataType.INTEGER ,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataType.TEXT,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true
        }
         },
         street: {
            type: DataType.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            validate : {
                notEmpty: true
            }

         },
         city: {
            type: DataType.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            validate:{
                notEmpty: true
            }
         },
         state: {
            type: DataType.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            validate:{
                notEmpty: true
            }
         },
         zip: {
            type: DataType.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            validate:{
                notEmpty: true
            }
         } 
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: (models) => {
                Locations.hasMany(models.Readings);
            }
        }
    });
    return Locations;
}
```

models/readings.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataType) => {
    const Readings = sequelize.define("Readings",{
        id: {
            type: DataType.INTEGER ,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        date: {
            type: DataType.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true
        }
         },
         temperature: {
            type: DataType.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            validate : {
                notEmpty: true
            }

         },
         humidity: {
            type: DataType.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            validate:{
                notEmpty: true
            }
         }
         
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: (models) => {
                Readings.belongsTo(models.Locations);
            }
        }
    });
    return Readings;
}
```

Comment: It's `.findAll()` not `.findALL()`.

Comment: ... wow, i cant believe it was such a small typo. Thank you so much